# Accessing value of iterated field in Mustache PHP

Tags: php, arrays, templates, mustache

Say I have an array in PHP that looks like so:

```
    $values = Array(
        '0' => 'value1',
        '1' => 'value2',
        '2' => 'value3'
    )
```

I'd like to iterate through the array using Mustache but I'd like the associated value. This is what I'm hoping to do:

```
    {{#values}}
        {{the current value}}
    {{/values}}
```

I hope there returned result would be:

```
    value1
    value2
    value3
```

I've been getting around this by changing my structure to:

```
    $values = Array(
        '0' => array('value=' =>'value1'),
        '0' => array('value=' =>'value2'),
        '0' => array('value=' =>'value3'),
    )
```

And call {{valule}} inside the Mustache iterator.

Should I be doing this a completely different way? I'm using a SplFixedArray in PHP and I'd like to iterate through the values using this method...

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The implicit Iterator is the way to go for simple data. If your data is more complex then PHPs ArrayIterator does the job well.

Here is an example that I have working. Hope it is useful for somebody else.

```
$simple_data = array('value1','value2','value3');   
$complex_data = array(array('id'=>'1','name'=>'Jane'),array('id'=>'2','name'=>'Fred') );

$template_data['simple'] = $simple_data;
$template_data['complex'] = new ArrayIterator( $complex_data ); 

$mustache->render('template_name', $template_data );
```

And in the template you could have

```
{{#simple}}
      {{.}}<br />
{{/simple}}

{{#complex}}
   <p>{{ id }} <strong>{{ name }}</strong></p>
{{/complex}}
```

Comment: Your answer help me a lot! I found wrapping the data with ArrayIterator as a very nice and simple way to iterate over php associative arrays to avoid transforming them into views.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the implicit iterator feature of mustache for this:

https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php/tree/master/examples/implicit_iterator

```
{{#values}}
    {{.}}
{{/values}}
```

Your original array probably needs numeric keys and now string though. It might work that way, but I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a super old php framework, which was using smarty like syntax but double curly braces, kept me hanging for quite sometime, so the following made the loop run for me :) maybe it will help you too.

```
{{ #each link in bluelinks }}
  <p><strong>{{ link }}</strong></p>
{{/each}}
```